# need help regarding the code to be written in "FLOW"

Tags: corda

I'm trying to build a **CordApp** that has three participants, say:

- PartyA
- PartyB
- PartyC

I've written the code for state and contract, but I need help regarding the code to be written in the flow.

I need to make sure that the flow is initiated only by **PartyA**, but the signatures of all the three participants are required.

**Questons:**

1. How do I proceed with the code?
2. When I'm declaring the participants and other variables in the flow, should I declare all of them?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check your current node using `getOurIdentity()` function. So you can put some if condition inside your flow method to verify that you are running the flow only from PartyA.
2. You can add the required signature in the below format when you are adding the command to the transaction builder.

   ```
   transactionBuilder.addCommand(new BookingContract.Commands.Issue() ,
   ImmutableList.of(issuer.getOwningKey(),owner.getOwningKey()));
   ```
3. Yes, you have to declare the Participants and other variables that are required to initiate the flow.